# How to make widget argument optional?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, flutter-widget, flutter-image

I have a function that I use to build an icon widget:

```
  buildIcon(IconData icon, Color color, VoidCallback onTap, {double? size}) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Icon(
        // set size only if argument size != null
        icon,
        color: color,
      ),
    );
  }
```

As you can see this function has nullable argument `size`. And I need this parameter to be set only if it is not equal to null. If I add a check for null, then I will have to add a default value for the `size` parameter of the icon widget.

Is it possible to avoid setting the `size` parameter of `Icon` widget if the function argument is null ? Please, help me.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am understanding something wrong, but why don't you set 
size: size ?
I guess the internal default value of the size parameter of the Icon widget is already null. 
This means:
when no size is provided, the value is null -> same value as you wouldn't set a size and when a size is provided, the value is the passed value

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, `Icon`'s `size` parameter is already optional. If it's not defined, it will be set to 24px, like you defined your method like this:

```dart
buildIcon(IconData icon, Color color, VoidCallback onTap, {double? size}) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Icon(
        icon,
        size: size ?? 24,
        color: color,
      ),
    );
  }
```

as seen [in the flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Icon/size.html):

> If there is no IconTheme, or it does not specify an explicit size, then it defaults to 24.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
buildIcon(IconData icon, Color color, VoidCallback onTap, {double? size = 10}) {
return InkWell(
  onTap: onTap,
  child: Icon(
    // set size only if argument size != null
    icon,
    color: color,
  ),
);
```

}

or:

```
 buildIcon(IconData icon, Color color, VoidCallback onTap, {double? size}) {
size ??= 10;
return InkWell(
  onTap: onTap,
  child: Icon(
    // set size only if argument size != null
    icon,
    color: color,
  ),
);
```

}